# How to get second occurrence of a value in python array and set color to it?

Tags: python

I have an array, 'labels'. I am setting colors to each unique value in array. As you see value '2' is occurring twice in the array. I want to get the second occurrence of '2' in the array and set color of the second occurrence as color=[0,0,0]. It is not just '2' but any value from the array which appears for second time.

For example if labels = [1 4 1 2], then its the second occurrence of '1' I want to set color as [0,0,0].  Please help!

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array([4, 2, 1, 2])
custom_colors = []
check_colors = []

for i in range(len(labels)):
  check_colors.append(labels[i])

  if labels[i]==1:  
    color = [1,0,0]
    custom_colors.append(color)
  elif labels[i]==2:  
    color=[.5,.5,.5]
    custom_colors.append(color)
  elif labels[i]==3: 
    color =[0,0,1]
    custom_colors.append(color)
  else:
    color = [0,1,0]  
    custom_colors.append(color)
      
print(check_colors)
print(custom_colors)
```

Comment: `labels[i] in labels[:i]` is a condition that would be true on the second (and subsequent) occurrence of a value.

Comment: Is it any occurrence after the first? You're appending the label to `check_colors`, so just check if the label is already in `check_colors`. If not, assign a color, if so, assign black.

Comment: @ddejohn yes its any occurrence after the first. But the ```check_colors``` has all values. It would only return true if present in that list

Answer (score 2):

Keep a set of the items you've seen before.  If the new item is in the set, substitute black.

```
import numpy as np

labels = np.array([4, 2, 1, 2])
custom_colors = []
check_colors = set()
colors = ([0,0,0],[1,0,0],[.5,.5,.5],[0,0,1],[0,1,0])

for i in labels:
    if i in check_colors:
        custom_colors.append(colors[0])
    else:
        check_colors.add(i)
        custom_colors.append(colors[i])

print(check_colors)
print(custom_colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a more pythonic approach, by using the data structures in a better way and list comprehension -

```
import numpy as np

###################################
#Colors for existing labels
c = {
     1:[1,0,0],
     2:[.5,.5,.5],
     3:[0,0,1],
}

#Colors if label doesnt exist or > 4
d = [0,1,0]

#Colors if second occurance of any label
e = [0,0,0]
###################################

labels = np.array([4,1,2,1])
_, idx = np.unique(labels, return_index=True) #get first indexes

custom_colors = [c.get(j, d) if i in idx else e for i,j in enumerate(labels)]

print(custom_colors)
```

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0, 0, 0]]
```